# How can I only make table headers center and bold?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to center and bold the table header. Here are codes.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\caption{table decription}
\label{t_sim}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Key & Value \\
\hline
$x$ & description of x \\
$y$ & description of y \\
$y$ & description of z \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

The results is:

[image]

**Problems need to be solved:**

- center the whole table
- center the table header only (the column titles, the first row, `key | value`)
- bold the table header
- why is the gap between `TABLE II` and `TABLE DISCRIPTION` so huge?

---

Thanks **@Christian Hupfer**, here is my result. The gap between `TABLE II` and `TABLE DISCRIPTION` is still huge? BTW, I use **IEEEtran**.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

[image]

Comment: Center the table header? You mean the column titles should be centered?

Comment: yes, the column titles (the first row, `key  value`).

Comment: I don't get that gap with `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`. Output is shown in my answer below for `article`, `IEEEtran` and `IEEEtran` with option `conference`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is to use the `makecell` package, which is done for formatting column heads. In addition, for free, you have that, by default, the contents of column heads are centred, both vertically and horizontally, and they can have line breaks. Here are two ways, with and without vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{table description}
  \label{t_sim}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \thead{Key} & \thead{Value} \\
    \hline
    $x$ & description of x \\
    $y$ & description of y \\
    $y$ & description of z \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\vskip1cm

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{table description}
  \label{t_sim}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    \thead{Key} & \thead{Value} \\
    \midrule
    $x$ & description of x \\
    $y$ & description of y \\
    $y$ & description of z \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `\centering` inside the `\begin{table}...\end{table}` pair, this is safe, since it's inside a group and won't bleed into the following text...
2. Use `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Key}}` for the first column and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Value}}` for the 2nd column. Note that the 2nd is `c|` and not `|c|`, otherwise the `|` would be doubled.
3. `\textbf{Key}` etc. for bold font text

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{table description}
\label{t_sim}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Key}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Value}} \\
\hline
$x$ & description of x \\
$y$ & description of y \\
$y$ & description of z \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. One more question, why is the gap between `TABLE II` and `TABLE DISCRIPTION` so huge?

Comment: No comments on the vertical lines!

Comment: @SparkandShine: In my output it's not really large. Do you have other spacings?

Comment: it might be my problem. All the `caption` has the same problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in a float; just `\centering`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, you're right of course. Since I never use floats for my personal documents I was too quick and did not thought about the `\begin{center}...` stuff

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's one of the most common “errors” found in documents; not the worst, of course, but it will cause misalignment of a top float, because of the added space.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, as I wrote: I don't use floats personally (they are no use on onesided worksheets and lab instructions for pupils), but besides that, I never liked them, so I am not really into correct usage of them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using `booktabs` and `makecell`. The results are different with `IEEEtran.cls`, however. (See below: this is why a Minimum Working Example is so important.)

`\centering` is a better option than the `center` environment within floats (e.g. `table`, `figure` etc.) as it avoid adding excessive vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}% bold tabular headers
\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}% centred tabular headers
\renewcommand\theadgape{}% booktabs rules already add vertical spacing
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering% will not add additional vertical space as center will - since table already adds spacing, you do not want extra here
  \caption{table decription}
  \label{t_sim}
  \begin{tabular}{*{2}{l}}
    \toprule% professional horizontal rules of variable weight from booktabs
    \thead{Key} & \thead{Value}\\
    \midrule% professional horizontal rules of variable weight from booktabs
    $x$ & description of x \\
    $y$ & description of y \\
    $y$ & description of z \\
    \bottomrule% professional horizontal rules of variable weight from booktabs
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancier tabular]

Switching the class to `IEEEtran.cls` produces this:

[image: IEEEtran version]

Here is the result shown with some dummy text to illustrate placement:

[image: IEEEtran placement]

Here is the result with the `conference` option for the class:

[image: conference variation]

If you are preparing a manuscript for submission, don't bother formatting things as you want as you will need to stick to the required style provided by the class etc. anyway. If you are not preparing for submission, you will find life easier if you use a more general-purpose class designed for greater flexibility.